# Estimating the sum of 4th powers of singular values?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix with $\operatorname{Tr}(AA^T)=1$. Let $\sigma_i$ be the vector of singular values of $A$. How would I cheaply estimate the following quantity?

$$\rho(A)=\sum_i \sigma_i^4$$

Motivation: $1/\rho(A)$ is a measure of "effective rank" of $AA^T$, a numerically stable  alternative to algebraic rank. Called $R$ in Bartlett [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.11300), Definition 3.

Comment: You mean apart from $Tr((AA^T)^2)$? At some point the SVD becomes cheaper than the multiple full matrix products.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thanks, that was a useful tip since that quantity is just the sum over squares of pairwise row dot products, which we can estimate using subset of rows

Answer (score 4):

Following the suggestion of Lutz, sum of fourth powers of singular values is just $\operatorname{Tr}((AA^T)^2)=\|AA^T\|_F^2=\sum_{ij} \langle a_i, a_j\rangle^2$ where $a_i$ is i'th row of $A$

Treating row indices $i$,$j$ as uniform random variables in $1\ldots,n$, we have:

$$\sum_{ij} \langle a_i, a_j\rangle^2=n E_i\langle a_i, a_i\rangle^2+n(n-1)E_{i\ne j}\langle a_i, a_j\rangle^2$$

Using 10% of the rows to [approximate](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-sum-of-singular-vals.nb) expectations appears to give reasonable result:

[image]